# Why GooglePlus Service.Activities.Items list is empty

Tags: google-plus

I want to get the URL of the photo shared to me. 
I'm using Google Plus Service API to get the list of the activities.

Initial OAuth dance was success, then, i trying to get list of all activities like this:

```
var activityReq = Program.GooglePlusService.Activities.List("me",ActivitiesResource.Collection.Public);
ActivityFeed all = activityReq.Fetch();
```

when i checked activity feed, it is empty, any idea why? what i'm doing wrong?
[image: Below figure shows this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two important things to note about activity listing:

1. `ActivitiesResource.Collection.Public` requests, as its name suggests, only public activities. If the photo was shared publicly, it can be retrieved. If it was shared only to you, or to a limited circle that you are part of, then it can't be used using Public. Currently there are no other collections available.
2. The id of "me" indicates that it should look through the collection of things that **you have shared**, not through collections of things that are public to you. If you want to look at what someone else has shared, you will need to get and specify their ID (that long number that is on their profile, or use the [People.search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) API method).